# Is it possible to use different sample weights for each row when fitting linear (ridge) regression in BigQuery ML?

Tags: machine-learning, google-bigquery

We are fitting the following example linear regression in BigQuery ML using the `l2_reg` parameter for "ridge" regression:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL `models.test_model`
  OPTIONS (
    model_type='linear_reg',
    l2_reg = 10
  ) AS
(
  select 3.4 as label, 1 as wt, 23 as x1, 8 as x2 union all
  select 2.4 as label, 1 as wt, 13 as x1, 23 as x2 union all
  select 1.6 as label, 1 as wt, 53 as x1, 52 as x2 union all
  select 6.5 as label, 2 as wt, 43 as x1, 12 as x2 union all
  select 4.2 as label, 2 as wt, 25 as x1, 23 as x2 union all
  select 5.2 as label, 2 as wt, 17 as x1, 35 as x2
)
```

We would like to fit a weighted ridge regression model, where the errors are weighted using the `wt` column. Certain rows in our data are of more importance than others, and using the `wt` column to assign weights to errors for each row will allow us to take row-importance into consideration. Tools like [scikit learn in python](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) allow for sample_weights for each observation. Is this possible with BQML with linear regression?